# Convolution using Matlab's conv() function

Tags: matlab, convolution

This is a supplementary question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023281/convolution-using-valid-in-matlabs-conv-function).

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html),

```
len(output) = len(input) + len(kernel) - 1
```

So, I figured out

- In case of `conv(u,v,"full")`:

  ```
  len(pad) = len(kernel) - 1
  ```

For instance, according to Matlab commandline:

```
    u = [1 2 1 3]
    v = [2 0 1]
    w = [2 4 3 8 1 3]
```

Coz,

```
    len(w) = len(u) + len(v) - 1 
           = 4 + 3 - 1 
           = 6 

    len(pad) = len(v) - 1
             = 3 - 1
             = 2
```

So, according to calculation:

```
0 0 1 2 1 3 0 0
1 0 2
---------------
0 0 2 = 2

. . . . . .
. . . . . .

0 0 1 2 1 3 0 0
          1 0 2
-------------------
          3 0 0 = 3
```

- In case of `conv(u,v,"same")`:

  ```
  u = [1 2 1 3]
  v = [2 0 1]
  w = [4 3 8 1]
  ```

Coz,

```
    len(w) = len(u) 
           = 4 

    len(pad) = floor(len(v) / 2)
             = floor(3 / 2)
             = 1
```

So, according to calculation:

```
0 1 2 1 3 0
1 0 2
-----------
0 0 4 = 4

. . . . . .
. . . . . .

0 1 2 1 3 0
      1 0 2
---------------
      1 0 0 = 1
```

But, problem arises in case of the following example:

```
    u = [1 2 1 3 1]
    v = [2 0 1 0]
```

The following one is okay:

- In case of `conv(u,v,"full")`:

  ```
  w = [2 4 3 8 3 3 1 0]       

  len(w) = len(u) + len(v) - 1 
         = 5 + 4 - 1 
         = 8 

  len(pad) = len(v) - 1
           = 4 - 1
           = 3
  ```

So,

```
0 0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 2
---------------------
0 0 0 2 = 2

. . . . .
. . . . .

0 0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0 0
              0 1 0 2
---------------------------
              0 0 0 0 = 0
```

**But, the following one has issues:**

- In case of `conv(u,v,"same")`:

  ```
  w = [3 8 3 3 1]
  ```

Coz,

```
    len(w) = len(u) 
           = 5 

    len(pad) = floor(len(v) / 2)
             = floor(4 / 2)
             = 2
```

So, according to calculation:

```
0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0
0 1 0 2
---------------
0 0 0 4 = 4

0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0
  0 1 0 2
---------------
  0 1 0 2 = 3

0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0
    0 1 0 2
---------------
    0 2 0 6 = 8

0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0
      0 1 0 2
-----------------
      0 1 0 2 = 3

0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0
        0 1 0 2
-------------------
        0 3 0 0 = 3

0 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 0
          0 1 0 2
-------------------
          0 1 0 0 = 1
```

I.e. output = `[4 3 8 3 3 1]` which doesn't match the Matlab output.

**What is going on here?**

Comment: For the case of `same`, the amount of padding added to one side is `floor(len(v)/2)`, and to the other side is `ceil(len(v)/2)`. Actually, padding is added as needed to produce an output of the required size.

Comment: @CrisLuengo For a `v` of length `4`, `u` is padded with 1 zero on the left and 2 on the right when you use `'same'`. You can confirm this by doing `conv([ 0 u 0 0], v, 'valid')`, which should give the same results as `conv(u, v, 'same')`.

Comment: Not arbitrarily, in a consistent and pre-determined manner. But the best way to define the padding is “however much is necessary”. It is likely that the code doesn’t do any actual padding, as that is pretty inefficient, but the output is consistent with padding.

Comment: @beaker: so `floor` on the left and `ceil` in the right. Thanks! Oh, I mis-typed above, I meant `floor((len(v)-1)/2)`.